# Changing ticks on Jupyter Notebooks from csv

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I've been trying to change the tick label of my axis. I've imported them from a csv, and have changed the label, but I can't change the tick. I'm just starting out, so if I have any of the terms wrong just let me know. My code is outlined below.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv ('countries.csv')
uk = data[data.ISO_3_CODE == "GBR"]

plt.plot(uk.date_epicrv)
plt.plot(uk.CumCase)
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel("Cumulative infection rate")

plt.show
```

The csv can be found at https://data.humdata.org/dataset/coronavirus-covid-19-cases-and-deaths if you need it. Sorry I couldn't be more specific, trying to learn a new skill and I believe I'm using the wrong terms to search.

Comment: Provide some more details about what exact output you are expecting.

Comment: I've found the issue with my syntax outlined below. Thank you for commenting.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I feel like a fool. I was formatting my graph wrong. 
Where I had

```
plt.plot(uk.date_epicrv)
plt.plot(uk.CumCase)
```

I should have used

```
plt.plot(uk.date_epicrv, uk.CumCase)
```

I was trying to plot both graphs on the x-axis. Closing the question now, hope this helps anyone with the issue down the line.